# Check for X instances in a regex

Tags: regex

How can I check if a given string contains X capitals, Y digits and Z non word characters? These numbers must be defineable in the regex.

So for example

`hereisMy1String`

Does it contain: 2 digits (or any given number), 2 capitals (or any given number) and a non word character (or multiple)?

The numbers/letters/characters can be in any position within the string.

Comment: You need something like `^(?=(?:\D*\d){2})(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:\w*\W){1})`

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "not work" - http://ideone.com/91izLw. The string you provided has no non-word chars.

Comment: This is a classic case of just don't do it in a single expression. The code becomes a million times easier to read if you don't try to force it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the answer that worked was:

`#(?=(\D*\d){2})(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})(?=([^\W_]*[\W_]){1})#`